# Considering the different implementations of sequence/auto-increment, how can I create an SQL insert statement that will work across different rdbms?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

I am trying to make a method for a class that will automatically insert a record into a table. The problem is that I need to make the code work for mysql, mssql, postgresql, oracle, and sqlite.

The only solutions I can think of are:

1. Create my own primary key values, but this seems very risky as it may be hard to come up with a fail-safe solution to generate the primary key values.
2. Create code that will switch the method used based on the rdbms driver being used, but this seems sloppy and I would like to use an SQL standards compliant way if possible.

**How can I create this `INSERT` statement to work accross all of these rdbms if they all use different methods for auto incrementing a primary key field?**

Comment: What language are you writing your application in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use specialized code per-rdbms.

Standard compliance is nice, but there are too many things that don't work on all of the databases. Starting with simple things like quoting of fields and values, things like limiting resultset to given number of rows, and possibly hundreds of other cases.

Answer (score 2):

**Pure Generic**

The only guaranteed portable way to do this across every conceivable database, and only have one single implementation; is to have the application generate the keys as [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)s and insert them as regular fields. The upside is you don't need to rely on some language or library specific implementation to retrieve the key, you already have it.

An alternative to [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) if you are doing data warehousing and not updating the rows after they are `INSERT`ed is a cryptographic hash of the contents of the row. Have your application concatenate all the fields contents to one single string and pull a SHA1 hash of that string. That key is for all practical purposes guaranteed to be unique for those contents. Makes replication and finding duplicate records a snap as well.

Sequential numbers are not the end all be all of primary keys.

[UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) keys are easier to port, and in 2011, they are just as fast when indexing and space should not be an issue unless you have Facebook or Google size data and then you have the money to buy the disk space you need, they use something other than a `long` number as well.

Another benefit is you can also do replication much easier because you don't have to worry about every database you try to sync with having a duplicate key.

**SQL Generic**

You can just leave off the field in the `INSERT` statement and the database will take care of creating the value for you.

**PHP** is going to make retrieving the auto-generated keys a problematic to do it in a generic way. Everything I can find about the topic is very specialized to whatever database is being used, there doesn't seem to be a generic API equivalent to JDBC for PHP.

**If you were using Java**

If you use the [boolean execute(String sql,
                int autoGeneratedKeys)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) on the [Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) class. You can tell it which field index the auto generated key is in and it will return it using [ResultSet getGeneratedKeys()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29).

**Oracle Specific**

If you set the `DEFAULT` value on the desited auto increment field in your `DDL` to call a function that selects the next value from a `sequence` you can implement the desired auto increment behavior in Oracle as well.

**NOTE**

[UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) is sometimes called [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier), and are technically different but conceptually the same thing.

Comment: To complete the picture: `getGeneratedKeys()` also works with Oracle if the value is generated in a trigger

Comment: Regarding the cryptographic hash approach: How would you handle UPDATEs? Either you have to update your primary key (a complete No-Go IMO), or you'll have inconsistencies between your hash and your actual data and might even run into false duplicate primary key issues.

Comment: @Frank they don't say anything about `UPDATE` statement, just `INSERT`. And for some cases, like data warehousing the SHA1 hash approach is ideal.

Comment: I wouldn't like 128 bit UUIDs as primary key if 32 bit would be sufficent. Thats plain waste of ressources IMO

Comment: "waste of resources" is subjective and specific the requirements, which we don't have. I opted for the most general solution. Obviously smaller bit size keys can be applicable, that is for the OP to decide. But the concept of a UUID/GUID is the same regardless of bit length barring collision concerns. Smaller bit lengths will collide faster.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing problematic in just inserting records with an auto-increment field: typically you just omit that field in the insert, the database generate it as a computed default value (that's why it's called "auto-increment").

The portability problem arises only when you need to get the value of that generated field (which frequently is a surrogate primary key). No standard SQL way for getting that.

*EDITED:* oook. As per comments, regarding my first paragraph  (the second paragraph stands) :

It's true that not every database supports straighforward out-of-box "DEFAULT" autoincrement fields (mea culpa). However, IF you have stipulated a schema design that supports this kind of insertion (straigtforward in Postgresql, Mysql, MSSQL and -I think- SQLite; not direct but possible -with triggers- in Oracle), THEN you can code your SQL INSERTS in a simple and portable way. ELSEWHERE, you cannot: in that case you must write rdbms-specific INSERTS.

Comment: -1 since not all databases support auto-increment fields (e.g. Oracle)

Comment: Oracle does support auto-increment, you just have to write a function to call the `sequence` and set that function as the `DEFAULT` value on a 'NOT NULL` field.

Comment: Yes, but that's not portable, as requested by the OP. You could also define a before insert trigger that fetches sequence.nextval and sets the PK, but IMHO, that's beside the point.

Comment: `DDL` isn't portable, never has been, having specific `DDL` isn't excluded by the posters question. The portable part they are concerned with is the application code, and that can definitely be made portable.

Comment: @Jarrod emphasizes the important part. There is no good way to create such a table (DDL), but JDBC abstracts you away from that. (Even more so something like Hibernate.) So client-side, you can just do an INSERT without setting the ID column and retrieve the new ID with getGeneratedKeys.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus : the posters question, IMO, is about plain standard SQL

Comment: @leonbloy, No, I read it that the poster is writing Java that he wants to work against diverse back-ends.

Comment: @everyone, the OP question is about standard SQL `INSERT` statements working with the different implemenations of auto-increment in the RDBMS, **not about retrieving the keys in any way much less a standard way**. I adding information about retrieving the keys to my answer simply because they are pretty useless without being able to retrieve them immediately after the `INSERT`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an ORM?  PHP has a ton of them:
Doctrine, Redbean, and many [others](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software)

The point of an ORM is to abstract the database layer. This sounds like what you need. You method would deal with objects in your code and the ORM has the custom code needed to persist those objects into your database

Comment: and yet my task is to build a custom orm

Comment: ah ok.  That wasn't clear in the question.  I would think then that the examples provided in the many existing ORMs would be a good guiding point.